# How can I add additional resolution for my screen?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, wine, xrandr

I tried to launch a game (GTA San Andreas) on wine.

GTA showed `Cannot find 800x600x32 video mode` and closed immediately.

The Computer I currently have is a Lenovo IdeaPad G510, with Intel HD Graphics 4600 graphical processor. I didn't change anything in wine settings. My OS is Debian 7.5 (wheezy).

I googled and got the error `"Cannot find 800x600x32 video mode"` is caused by my graphical card not supporting resolution requested by GTA resolution.

I ran `xrandr` command and got:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
minimum 1366 x 768, current 1368 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768 default
connected 1368x768+0+0
0mm x 0mm    1366x768        0.0      1368x768  0.0*
```

As I can see `800 x 600` isn't an available resolution for my screen.

- Is there any way to add it?
- Should I edit Xorg configuration file, etc. ?

Comment: Run `xrandr` in a terminal, and check if you get the desired resolution in there. If not, you may use `cvt` to set a new resolution - You can get the details in **[this page](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html)**, and **[this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)** as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is Grand Theft Auto 3: San Andreas's 800x600x32 resolution just for the menu to work? If not you can emulate such a window using Wine and then in the game's menu set your specific resolution.

If yes, then you may also try using `xrandr`'s scaling arguments:

> ```
> --scale xxy
>         Changes the dimensions of the output picture. Values superior to
>         1 will lead to a compressed screen (screen dimension bigger than
>         the dimension of the output mode), and values below 1 leads to a
>         zoom in on the output. This option is actually a  shortcut  ver‐
>         sion of the --transform option.
>
> info xrandr
> ```